# How to include gruntfile.js in existing yeoman project

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I have angular project generated by yeoman but it don't have `gruntfile.js` , how to include `gruntfile.js` in existing yeoman project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like yeoman is not  scaffolded properly. Follow http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html and try to scaffold again.